# Save input values from Custom Activity - Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I am building a custom activity in journey builder. I am trying to save the values to update without losing my initial input. Once I hit save and reopen the custom activity, my inputs are reset to null. Anyone know how this can be achieved? Thank you!!! [image][image][image][image]

Comment: The saving and initiating of the values you input are handled by your postmonger script. It will be easier to help you if you post what you have so far in that script.

Answer (score 0):

I go about doing this by tagging a function that parses upon init.
This will work if the param is parsed into the payload.

```
connection.on('initActivity', initialize);
function initialize(data) {
    if (data) {
        payload = data;
    }
    initialLoad(data);
}

function initialLoad (data) {
    //Function that loads data into your Front End UI goes here.
    // e.g. $('inputfield').val(savedData.arguments.execute.inArguments[0].<config_json_param>);
};
```